# Slide show using javascript cause Highcharts size changed. May i know why?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have whole list of highcharts which I will display it one by one using slide showw method. For the first slide show, my highcharts display perfectly with 100% width. But second slide show and onward, the highcharts size change to default side which doesnt follow my css attribute 100%. May i know why ?

As my understanding, highcharts will change the size according to my div tag.

My script as below

```
 <script>
var myIndex = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    carousel();
});

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("chartSlideShow");


    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        x[i].style.display = "none";

    }

    myIndex++;

    if (myIndex > x.length) {
        myIndex = 1
    }

    x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "inline-block";

    if (myIndex != x.length) {
        setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
    }

}
```

My cshtml page code as below

```
 @model Project.Models.ChartModel
 @if (Model.ListOfColumnChart != null && Model.ListOfColumnChart.Count != 0)
    {

        foreach (var chart in Model.ListOfColumnChart)
        {

    <div class="chartSlideShow" style="width:100%">
        @chart.columnChart

    </div>


        }
    }
```

Expected : 
All highcharts will show out with 100% width.

First Slide show it will show exactly 100% in width
[image: First Slide show it will show exactly 100% in width]

Second slide show it will go back to default size which is not 100%
[image: Second slide show it will go back to default size which is not 100%]

Appreciate if anyone of you could point out my mistake.

Comment: Could you show the chart options? It's hard to tell if it's a highcharts issue.